# Typescript won't spread generic parameters into matching function

Tags: typescript

I have an object that contains functions:

```
const bazApi = {
  fun1: () => string,
  fun2: (n: number) => void,
  fun3: (s: string) => Promise<number>,
}
```

Then I have a function that takes a key of that object and a tuple of parameters matching the input of the associated function, i.e. `fun2` and `[42]`. The function then uses the identifier to get the function from the object and calls it using the provided arguments. However, Typescript complains:

> A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)

I have read up on the error, but I don't think it is the underlying problem, which is rather TS suddenly not being able to match function and parameters.

Here is the code (and here it is at the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgLwIJgJYEkB2wICcBmcAxtALxQDeAUFLVPgK6YCMAXFABQCUUpAfFADOwXKkwBzADQ06jTACZ2HTO0wMAtgCM8PflABuAe1QATaXXpMAzEsHthoiboEAFXIfWpBEADxqteHzSAL5UVKCQUACyEIKCcOK+ACpQEAAeOJgmglAAShBEhrgmPgDSkpwAdNVwuOJ2UHCYIM6NzUFQpakZEFk5ANYQIIb4UEkC5NQWherqTSbs5TK0tfXsLrVw6hA4uII+SQDapQC6fFSh4eDQKKgAMl6ZeAfdmdl5BUUlg8OjSRUcaqVVYNJotXgCMF8CZQMqvXrvH4jMZ8DjLKDbOIJCDsGJYxIHCqlc6tIymMImAoAG1q0EKmGEUE0iFu7HgyDQWF2hBIVHpjKpj16eHYtwewmFuB87NuXLwPIgMI4mPiiVaUzo-OAlCgMzmWQqIKgwV4GNiqogAG50VqoAALeZUvCm5kc1CHPXzE6WiwAel9YwAykI4CAcg6sk7cFAvJZMERgKhDJh6O51LAWZzsPLiNAxJS0hATEyQFAAMIefUmAByW2gHHEhkMJi4NuTjNwsVNEZMUcBNTqgi4PostH9QZDYftjudsaYSZThn0zo4YgnABZKgB2SrrnhFRpmurQZEcAD8PDgVKpcYTC9THgzbrlBFznEwhm1jebreClqAA)):

```js
type BazApiInterface = {
    fun1: () => string,
    fun2: (n: number) => void,
    fun3: (s: string) => Promise<number>,
}

type Message<T extends Record<K, (...args: any) => any>, K extends keyof T> = {
    command: K,
    args: Parameters<T[K]>
}

type ApiListener<T extends Record<keyof T, (...args: any) => any>> = <K extends keyof T>(
    message: Message<T, K>
) => void

declare const bazApi: BazApiInterface
const listener: ApiListener<BazApiInterface> = (message) => {
    const { command, args } = message;
    const handler = bazApi[command];    // TS says handler is function from BazApiInterface indexed by CommandName (good)
    const res = handler(...args);       // TS says handler is union over (in TS 4.7.4) or a merge of (?) all function from BazApiInterface (not good)
};
```

Interestingly, in the line above the error, where `handler` is set, typescript seems to know that it is the function from the object identified by the command name, i.e. `BazApiInterface[K]`, and I can even get it to write it out as

```
const handler: ApiInterface<{
  fun1: () => string;
  fun2: (n: number) => void;
  fun3: (s: string) => Promise<number>;
}>[CommandName]
```

Also, `args` gives similar output, TS seems to know that it contains the parameters for the function identified by `CommandName`. So it seems like TS should be able to figure out that they match.

However, when actually calling the function in the next line, TS sees `handler` either as a union type over all functions in the object (in TS v4.7.4) or as some weird amalgamation of the functions (`(arg0: never) => string | void | Promise<number>`) in TS v4.9.5, and then correctly complains that something isn't right. But it would be if the function type hadn't changed, wouldn't it?

Currently, I just cheat (`const res = (handler as Function)(...args);`), but I would really like to know why it happens and if I can do anything about it?

Feels like this question is asked every other day, but I couldn't find an explanation. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73171228/4883195) and the linked [issue in TS' Github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) seems very close, but I don't think it applies (or at least I can't).

Comment: Note that `extends ScriptsApi` doesn't do much, or at least not what you want. `ScriptsApi` with no type argument evaluates to `{ [x: string]: any; }` (so you can write `ApiListener<{ a: 1, b: "oops" }>`). You might want to remove that constraint unless it does something useful in the question.

Comment: I'd say we should reduce your example code to [this version](https://tsplay.dev/mbEa3N) which has the same problem but not the unrelated weirdness.  Agreed?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Gladly, yes. Note though that `handler` now has a different type. Before, it was the type from the question with the individual functions, now it is just `const handler: BazApiInterface[K]`. Does this make a difference?

Comment: Isn't that the same type unless your type has non-functions in it?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpjAzw) meet your needs?  It is indeed the issue that ms/TS#47109 addresses, although I don't know if this refactoring is any more ergonomic for you than "cheating" would be, since it's annoying to lead the compiler through the logic here.  What's funny is that it almost resurrects the `ScriptsApi` type I told you to destroy earlier. Anyway if you want I could write this up as an answer, or let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Yes, I guess it is. It gave me comfort reading it literally, to eliminate any monkey business from going on, but you are right. Changed code and playground link.

Comment: @jcalz That's nice! I can use it like the `ScriptsApi` before (`type BazApiInterface = Api<{fun1: () => string, ...}>`, only now it works. The difference is that now the link between indentifier, function and its args is nailed down in the type, right? If you don't mind, I would appreciate a short explanation.

Comment: I'll write up an answer explaining when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having with

```
const res = handler(...args);
```

Is that the compiler can't follow the correlation between the type of `handler` and the type of `args`.  The error message about spread/rest is misleading, see [microsoft/TypeScript#47615](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47615).  The [`Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) is implemented as a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and is thus *deferred* when its argument is generic.  While a human being can read `func(...args)` where `func` is of generic type `F` and `args` is of generic type `Parameters<F>` and say "yeah that works", the compiler doesn't see it that way, since it doesn't really know the purpose of `Parameters`.  You can only call `func(...args)` generically if the compiler knows that `args` is of type `A` and `func` is of type `(...args: A) => any`.

---

If you want to try refactoring so the compiler *does* follow the correlation, you can indeed use the technique mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), where we try to represent things in terms of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into  [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

For example:

```
declare const bazApi: BazApiInterface

type Api<T extends Record<keyof T, (...args: any) => any>> =
    { [K in keyof T]: (...args: Parameters<T[K]>) => ReturnType<T[K]> }

const listener: ApiListener<BazApiInterface> =
    (message) => {
        const _bazApi: Api<BazApiInterface> = bazApi;
        const { command, args } = message;
        const handler = _bazApi[command];
        const res = handler(...args); // okay
    };
```

The `Api<T>` type is essentially an identity function on `T`, more or less, and indeed `Api<BazInterface>` is equivalent to `BazInterface`.  And the compiler is happy to allow you to assign `bazApi` to `_bazApi`. But since `Api<T>` is a mapped type, then so is the type of `_bazApi`.  So `_bazApi[command]` is now an indexed access into a mapped type, which the compiler can directly evaluate as being type `(...args: Parameters<BazInterface[K]>) => ReturnType<BazInterface[K]>`.  And since `args` is of type `Parameters<BazInterface[K]>`, the call succeeds.

Again, it might seem silly that you're rewriting `BazInterface` to an equivalent type and now things work, but you can think of it as leading the compiler through the exercise of understanding the generic relationship between `handler` and `args`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! If I understand it correctly, we have to tell the compiler *"the function you get through the identifier has the arguments of the function you get through the identifier"*, otherwise it is too loose for TS. Quite fascinating.